# Код выдаёт ошибку opencv

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

Написал простой код на основе cv2, просто что бы код демонстрировал происходящее с камеры, уже делал код в точь-точь как на ютубе и у других людей, но выдаёт всё время одну и туже ошибку.

Вот код:

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, img = capture.read()

    cv2.imshow('From Camera', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyALLWindows()
```

А вот ошибка которую выдаёт при запуске кода:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Scrapping1/hc.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('From Camera', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: проверьте наличие камеры в системе, либо попробуйте cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, вы должны проверять - было ли чтение с камеры успешным, для этого там и возвращается статус `ret`:

```
    ret, img = capture.read()
    if ret: 
        cv2.imshow('From Camera', img)
```

Причины неуспешного чтения могут быть разные. Если чтение всё время не успешное, то нужно уже разбираться дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что вы указали правильный путь к изображению и capture.read() действительно считывает картинку.

size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow' сообщает что изображение пришло пустое или битое, но с больше вероятностью некорректно задано расположение до файла.